# Creating I2C device driver struct setup

Tags: c, struct, linux-device-driver, i2c

I am writing a device driver which use I2C to communicate to host.

Below is the code I wanted to learn and understand. Do help me out If my understanding is wrong about the code below. "//" is my own comments & my understanding to the code.

```
// declare there will be a member struct inside the class example_state. This member is pointing to i2c_client.
struct example_state {
struct i2c_client *client; 
};

static int example_probe(struct i2c_client *client, const struct i2c_device_id *id{

// declare this to be a local struct inside the example_probe
struct example_state *state;

// get "struct device" to be pointed client's member name dev
// Question: is "struct device *dev" part of "struct i2c_client"?
// if "struct device *dev" imported from somewhere that why there is no need to allocate memory?
struct device *dev = &client->dev;

// allocate a memory space for "struct example_state"
// at this point "struct example_state" is still empty/NULL
// **Question:** but what is the relationship of this local "struct example_state"
// with the one declared before entering struct example_state function?
state = kzalloc(sizeof(struct example_state), GFP_KERNEL); 
if (state == NULL) {
    dev_err(dev, "failed to create our state\n");
    return -ENOMEM;
}

    // after memory allocated set the "struct i2c_client" point to "struct example_state"'s member namely "client".
state->client = client; 

   // set the our device I2C driver information to the host.
   // Question: Where to we set our device driver data?
i2c_set_clientdata(client, state); 

/* rest of the initialisation goes here. */

dev_info(dev, "example client created\n");

return 0;
}

static int __devexit example_remove(struct i2c_client *client){
  // get the loaded value from host, i guess is like unregister
  // my device driver information from the host when i exited.
struct example_state *state = i2c_get_clientdata(client);

kfree(state);
return 0;
}

static struct i2c_device_id example_idtable[] = {
{ "example", 0 },
{ }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest that instead of studying up on the Linux kernel's i2c support, you ought to take another look at [K&R 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) instead:

```
// declare there will be a member struct inside the class example_state. This member is pointing to i2c_client.
struct example_state {
struct i2c_client *client; 
};
```

C does not have classes. The Linux kernel's `sysfs` abstraction introduced the kernel's own idea of what a "class" is -- see `drivers/base/class.c` -- but it has no relationship at all to classes in C++, Java, C#, or any other language you're familiar with.

```
static int example_probe(struct i2c_client *client, const struct i2c_device_id *id{

// declare this to be a local struct inside the example_probe
struct example_state *state;
```

This declares `state` to be a *pointer* to a `struct example_state` piece of memory. (I'd normally use the word *object* here, but I don't want to counteract the "C does not have classes" speech from the previous paragraph. It's a piece of memory that is as large as or larger than the amount necessary to hold all the members of the `struct example_state`, and the compiler knows to check operations for type consistency. Maybe I should have just said "object"...)

In any event, there is only enough memory set aside in this line of code for a *pointer* -- not the structure itself.

```
// get "struct device" to be pointed client's member name dev
// Question: is "struct device *dev" part of "struct i2c_client"?
// if "struct device *dev" imported from somewhere that why there is no need to allocate memory?
struct device *dev = &client->dev;
```

The `struct device *dev` in this line allocates enough memory for a *pointer* and tells the compiler that the pointer will only point to `struct device` objects. The `=&client->dev` looks into the `client` parameter to find the `dev` member and makes an *alias* for easier use within this routine.

```
// allocate a memory space for "struct example_state"
// at this point "struct example_state" is still empty/NULL
// **Question:** but what is the relationship of this local "struct example_state"
// with the one declared before entering struct example_state function?
state = kzalloc(sizeof(struct example_state), GFP_KERNEL); 
if (state == NULL) {
    dev_err(dev, "failed to create our state\n");
    return -ENOMEM;
}
```

The `struct example_state { .. }` from earlier was a type declaration. It only instructed the compiler about the names, sizes, and types, of members stored in structs with the tag `struct example_state`. It does not allocate any memory. The `kzalloc()` call here *does* allocate memory, the size of our `struct example_state` objects, and it requests that the normal `GFP_KERNEL` memory allocation pool be used. See `include/linux/gfp.h` for details on the different "pools" of memory available. Depending upon the flags passed to the kernel's memory allocator, the memory allocation might happen only *after* the kernel has been forced to perform a "garbage collection" of sorts -- writing dirty memory buffers back to disk, dropping page caches, swapping processes, maybe even invoking the OOM memory killer to allocate memory. The `GFP_ATOMIC` pool is used when the kernel absolutely must not sleep at that point -- excellent for use when spinlocks are held or in interrupt context.

While it is possible to learn C and kernel internals simultaneously, it is a very unforgiving environment to make mistakes. Following a stray pointer in a normal userspace program segfaults the process but following a stray pointer in the kernel panics the machine or corrupts memory, filesystems, etc.

Comment: Hi sarnold, thank for the reply, finally i see some light. struct example_state *state; <-so it actually create a pointer type of struct example. where state->client = client; actually pass down the address from the pointer struct i2c_client *client to state pointer. Someone is passing down a type of struct i2c_client *client pointer. but how should I see this? the .probe is somehow is pointer function that link example_probe()?

Comment: `state->client = client` is an assignment; you're copying the value of the `client` pointer into the `.client` member of the structure pointed to by `state`. I wouldn't call that "passing down", but you otherwise sound like you've got it now. :)